# Where does Chrome DevTools store data for custom or build in devices on responsive test

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Where does Chrome DevTools store the Data for Emulated Devices (on testing Responsive)?

[image]

I know we can manually add Custom Devices by clicking on `Add Custom Device` but I need to input all devices at once so I can re-use them on other computer as well.

Comment: It's stored inside `Preferences` file in your browser profile,  devtools.preferences.customEmulatedDeviceList JSON subtree.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm, I find the `Preferences` and find the `customEmulatedDeviceList` there. Can you please let me know what language or markup is this? I tried to beautify it by JSON online beautifiers and it didn't work.

Comment: It's a JSON. Beautifiers are somewhat dumb so you may need to add `a=` before the text.

Comment: @Behseini where does one access the Preferences and the customEmulatedDeviceList ? Not sure how to find it in DevTools/Chrome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom):

> It's stored inside Preferences file in your browser profile, `devtools.preferences.customEmulatedDeviceList` JSON subtree